# How to subscribe objects without knowing their invoker's class?

Tags: c#, events, architecture, event-handling, structure

I have a **Scenario**, which uses **A** or several **As**. The **A** is being created outside of this **Scenario**, but **B** which is created inside of **A**, has no idea of Scenario its instance. And that's the idea, A and B don't have to know how Scenario works, they just have to work when the UpdateEvent is raised/invoked.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var sce1 = new Scenario();
            sce1.Add(new A(1));
            sce1.Add(new A(3));
            sce1.Update(2);
            sce1.Update(5);

            var sce2 = new Scenario();
            sce2.Add(new A(6));
            sce2.Update(0.3);

            Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }

    public class BasicEvent : EventArgs
    {
        public double Number { get; set; }
    }

    public abstract class toBeUpdated
    {
        public abstract void OnUpdate(object sender, BasicEvent e);
    }

    public class C : toBeUpdated
    {
        public double Number { get; set; }
        public C(double num)
        {
            Number = num * num;
        }
        public override void OnUpdate(object sender, BasicEvent e)
        {
            Number = Math.Pow(e.Number, 2);
        }
    }

    public class B : toBeUpdated
    {
        public double  Number { get; set; }
        public B(double num)
        {
            Number = num;
        }
        public override void OnUpdate(object sender, BasicEvent e)
        {
            Number *= e.Number;
        }
    }

    public class A : toBeUpdated
    {
        private B B1 { get; set; }
        private B B2 { get; set; }
        private C C1 { get; set; }
        public A(double number)
        {
            B1 = new B(number);
            B2 = new B(number);
            C1 = new C(number);
        }
        public override void OnUpdate(object sender, BasicEvent e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Updating A.. Data = {B1.Number + B2.Number * C1.Number}");
        }
    }

    public class Scenario
    {
        private event EventHandler<BasicEvent> UpdateEvent;
        private List<toBeUpdated> toKeepTrack { get; set; }
        public Scenario()
        {
            toKeepTrack = new List<toBeUpdated>();
        }
        public void Add(toBeUpdated obj)
        {
            toKeepTrack.Add(obj);
            UpdateEvent += obj.OnUpdate;
        }
        public void doSomethingWithTheList()
        {
            ....
        }
        public void Update(double num)
        {
            UpdateEvent?.Invoke(this, new BasicEvent() { Number = num });
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
```

I need several Scenarios to be created, I can't make it static.

Comment: Is `A` & `B` only subscribing to one instance of `Scenario` or multiple at the same time?

Comment: @Hayden Just one

Comment: Is your question "Existed `A` and `B` have to subscribe to different `Scenario`"?

Comment: @LouisGo No, it's the same Scenario for A and the Bs created inside A

Comment: I did not get your question. `A` and `B`'s `OnUpdate` have to subscribe to `Scenario`'s event. By this way, `A` and `B` do not really know who calls `OnUpdate`. However you think this is not enough, because you want to "make them static". I can't get why you want to "make them static". There must be some points you did not post on this question. I might misunderstand your question.

Comment: @LouisGo i don't want to make Scenario static, i said i have to create several Scenarios

Comment: Let's put several Scenario a side, what makes you "have to" make scenario static. I think it's the missing link. You want to achieve something but only come up with "make `Scenario` static". Elaborate on "what do you want to achieve."

Comment: Is this code snippet enough? `Scenario s = new Scenario();` `A a = new A();` `s.UpdateEvent += a.OnUpdate;` You don't have to put `A` into `Scenario`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this use case, I think the best approach would be to create an interface `IScenario` and let `Scenario` extend this interface. This will *hide* the implementation details of `Scenario`, and allow you to pass `IScenario` directly into the constructor of `A`.

```
public interface IScenario
{
    void Add(toBeUpdated obj);
    void Update(int num);
}
```

Which you can now extend `Scenario` like so:

```
public class Scenario : IScenario
{
    ...
}
```

Update `A` accordingly:

```
public class A : toBeUpdated
{
    ...
    public A(int number, IScenario scenario)
    {
        B1 = new B(number);
        scenario.Add(this);
        scenario.Add(B1);
    }
    ...
}
```

How to use would be something like:

```
var sce = new Scenario();
A a1 = new A(1, sce);
A a3 = new A(3, sce);
sce.Update(2);
sce.Update(5);
```

This approach ensures that `A` doesn't know the `Scenario` that it's updating with minimal effort, and is quite testable. Another approach is to add a method onto `A`, which *registers* a `Scenario` (useful if `A` needs to add a new `Scenario` after creation):

```
public void Register(IScenario scenario)
{
    scenario.Add(this);
    scenario.Add(B1);
}
```

**Note:** Creating the `IScenario` isn't *required*, but it's good to have when you get into `unit testing` and want to `mock` objects.

**Edit:** You can always use reflection to get all properties of type `toBeUpdated` from `A`:

```
// In Scenario
public void Add(toBeUpdated obj)
{
    UpdateEvent += obj.OnUpdate;

    // Get all properties of type toBeUpdated
    var properties = obj.GetType()
        .GetProperties(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static)
        .Select(x => x.GetValue(obj))
        .OfType<toBeUpdated>();

    foreach (var property in properties)
    {
        UpdateEvent += property.OnUpdate;
    }
}
```

Comment: i considered this solutions, but if i have several Bs? or several Cs? the idea is to make it dynamically

Comment: @Noxious How are several Bs or several Cs instantiated? Inside A like B1? If that's the case, are you able to update your post to showcase this?

Comment: sorry, it took me a while to make it a little more complex

Comment: @Noxious I've updated my answer accordingly, which should satisfy your needs.

Comment: i'm getting properties.Count() == 0, nothing happens
i will see more codes about GetProperties, Thanks a lot!
just one question, reflection is slow or not recommended for any reason?

Comment: @Noxious I've updated my answer with it now working. Reflection is slower than directly accessing the object. If you're concerned about performance, than my original solution is the best approach.

Comment: awesome, i just moved the line UpdateEvent += obj.OnUpdate;to the end because A's method was triggered first

Comment: @Noxious another way if you want to avoid reflection is to add a list to `A` and add `A` as a parameter to `B` and `C` constructor. From there, you can add the instance of `B` and `C` to that list and use that list in `Add`

Comment: Yes, i think that would be the best solution to avoid reflection. I will try both and see the difference in performance.